# How can I add an AddToFavorites link to a details page in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a details view with a sidebar and I would like to allow the user to add the current details to their favorites. I'm current using the following javascript, but I don't know how to pass the details id to the javascript to generate the link to be added to the users favorites.

My javascript - This doesn't work of course...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function addfav() 
    {
        if (document.all) 
        {
            window.external.AddFavorite("linkToDetailsScreen" , "FavoritesName")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.external.AddFavorite(location.href, document.title);
```

This adds a favorite for the current page/URL and takes the browser's window title for the favorite title. [See here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535926%28VS.85%29.aspx).

BTW: this solution only works in IE. See [here](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html), [here](http://calisza.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/javascript-jquery-bookmark-script/) or [here](http://www.dummwiam.com/jFav) for solution which also work in other browsers.

Comment: The target users for the application are all required to run IE, but the links will be helpful for other applications. Thanks.